# How to strip out certain fields from the Stack Exchange API, JSON response?

Tags: support, api-v2, filter

I want to fetch all my favorite questions on Stackoverflow.com and dump them as JSON. I used this API path:

```
/2.1/users/1310070/favorites?fromdate=1382486400&site=stackoverflow
```

But it is returning some fields which are not required like `upvote_count`, `downvote_count`, and `owner`.
Can I use the API in such a way that it does not return these fields?

This is to make my API calls light -- decrease the response size -- to save bandwidth (and time, and quota).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what [custom filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) are for.
For example, if you [append `&filter=!BGRhem4Z)WIti9lP55R*tgr(Jq_fHC` to your query, above](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users#fromdate=1382486400&order=desc&sort=activity&ids=1310070&filter=!BGRhem4Z%29WIti9lP55R*tgr%28Jq_fHC&site=stackoverflow&run=true), you will get results without `upvote_count`, `downvote_count`, or `owner` information. (The first two aren't included by default anyway.)

---

An easy way to create a filter is to use the filter-edit tool, on [the appropriate doc page for the path you are using](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/favorites-on-users). :

(Sample image of tool follows. It is not specific to this question)

[image: Filter tool]