# Total Number Of Answers

Tags: support, api, answers

I need to find the total number of answers submitted by a user on stackoverflow. I tried the following:

I got my json from the following:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/users/2440312/answers?site=stackoverflow
```

To get the total number of answers by the user_id I did:

```
json_object["items"].length
```

This however always returns me 30 if the number of answers by the user_id is more than 30. Is there a way I can get the actual number of answers by the user?

The [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) says that `users/user_id/answers/` should return the list of all answers by the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does return all the answers, but [they're paged](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging) - by default you'll only get 30 at a time. You'll likely want to increase `pagesize` to 100, and then add the additional code necessary to make subsequent requests if `has_more` is set on the response wrapper.

So, for example, your first request would be like

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/users/2440312/answers?site=stackoverflow&pagesize=100&page=1
```

and if the response had `had_more` you'd need to request

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/users/2440312/answers?site=stackoverflow&pagesize=100&page=2
```

and so on until `has_more` returns false. Be careful about requesting too quickly or you'll [be throttled](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

Comment: thanks a lot Tim! Can you also add how should the url be with the 'page_size' option.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the **total**, don't bother paging through the entire full result set.
Use the `total` property of [the Common Wrapper Object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper).  This will save lots of time and bandwidth and quota and doesn't require you to loop through the results just to count things.

The `total` property is not enabled by default, so you will need to [Create a custom filter](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653) for your queries. ([You should do this anyway, to speed your app up.](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters))

Here's how it looks for that `/users/{ids}/answers` route:
[/users/2440312/answers?site=stackoverflow&filter=!.UE8F0_EMkjmCAGv](https://api.stackexchange.com/users/2440312/answers?site=stackoverflow&filter=!.UE8F0_EMkjmCAGv)

Which currently yields:

```
{
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9993,
  "page": 1,
  "page_size": 30,
  "total": 41,
  "type": "answer"
}
```

---

Unfortunately, the API does not do subtotals.  So if you fetch more than one user at a time, this streamlined method will not work. (EG: [this two-user request](https://api.stackexchange.com/users/2440312%3B12579/answers?site=stackoverflow&filter=!.UE8F0_EMkjmCAGv) yields `total` = 3663 (at least 37 pages of answers) with no way to tell which user has which without paging through your original-style query.)

Comment: Thanks Brock for the tip :) . Actually I also wanted to filter total number of accepted answers and unaccepted answers. Is there a short way to get this too? I am currently checking each answer and its is_accepted' key for this.

Comment: Unfortunately no. API support for answer-search is still spotty and buggy.  To determine how many answers are accepted or not, you must page through, as you are currently doing, **or** you can scrape [the normal search page](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2440312+isaccepted%3Ayes) and parse the `results` display at the top.