# Where is "items" & "badge_counts" documentation?

Tags: support, api, documentation

Where is the `items` & `badge_counts` documentation?
This is returned as JSON. I am using the [/me/associated query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`items`** is documented in [the Common Wrapper Object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper). It is an array of whichever object the given route returns.

In the case of `/me/associated`,  `items` is an array of [`network_user` objects](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-user).

If you [use a filter](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653) that returns [`.wrapper.type`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper), then `type` will return the type that `items` has assumed. EG:

```
{
    "items": [                    // <=== Linked
        {
            "badge_counts": {
                "bronze": 123,
                "silver": 72,
                "gold": 8
            },
            "question_count": 11,
            "answer_count": 1241,
            ...
        },
        ...
    ],
    "quota_max": 10000,
    "total": 36,
    "type": "network_user"        // <=== Linked
}
```

---

**`badge_counts`** is documented in [the `badge_count` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/badge-count) and is just an object with 3 integer properties:

> **Fields**
>      bronze   integer
>      gold       integer
>      silver    integer

Comment: There should be new page for items (my suggestion is https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/items) like [network_user  - Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-user) is for network_user

Comment: Can't really document `items` more than [it already is](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper), because `items` is an array that *has a different type for each different API route*.  What else would you put in the doc page?