# Take the right filter for favourite count

Tags: support, api, filter

I try to take the favourite count filter for a question.

I use api through R

```
library(stackr)
    stack_questions(11227809, site = "stackoverflow", filter = "!GeD4JB*YQqe2L")
```

and I try to take the filter as [this](https://stackapps.com/a/6908/54551) way

However I receive this error

> Error in !metadata$has_more : invalid argument type

Also I tested the filter in api but again it gives an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're doing this call:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!GeD4JB*YQqe2L&site=stackoverflow&run=true

which indeed returns an empty object, since you only selected the `favorite_count` field, which is part of the question object, which is only returned if you select the `items` field in the `.wrapper`. Even then, it's not very useful since you don't know the ID of the question. Also, the 'stackr' library expects a `has_more` field which isn't in the filter either. It's easier to take the default filter and add the `favorite_count`, instead of starting from a blank filter. That filter value would be `!9_bDDnJE5` as the following page shows:

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!9_bDDnJE5&site=stackoverflow&run=true