# How to increase app request quota from 300 to 10,000?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, rate-limit, limits

In the app management page for a [little app I made](http://damndaniel.site), the following statement is presented below this key `Pw9D)judG8FE4tJR3qjUTA((`:

> Pass this as key when making requests against the Stack Exchange API
>   to receive a [higher request quota](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

Based on the "higher request quota" documentation, it's safe to assume that "higher request quota" is the upgrade from 300 to 10,000 requests per day per ip (my users are not authenticating). But, passing the key along with the initial request has had no affect, and I already verified multiple times that the key is correct. Here's the code for that call:

```
SE.init({
    clientId: 7265,
    key: 'Pw9D)judG8FE4tJR3qjUTA((',
    channelUrl: 'http://damndaniel.site/blank.html',
    complete: function (data) {
        // good to go...
    }
})
```

**How can I get the request quota to be 10,000?**

For more information about the call, [head over to the site](http://damndaniel.site) and open the console, the request object is being logged on every request. There you will see that the `quota_max` property remains at `300`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [the "Javascript SDK"](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) and that's not how it works.  The [doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/js-lib) calls the SDK "small and minimalistic".    [The source code](https://dev.sstatic.net/apiv2/js/all.js) states:

> This file is provided to API clients to automate various tasks, **initially focused on login**.

In fact the SDK really only does one thing.  It helps you get an `access_token` if you need to authenticate.  It doesn't help with anything else right now, nor has it ever.

**To take advantage of your key, you need to pass it in every API call.**

For example, compare:

- [api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1?site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1?site=stackoverflow&filter=!T6o*9_naf.jY-3uDW.) (has 300 quota)
  and
- [api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1?site=stackoverflow&key=Pw9D)judG8FE4tJR3qjUTA((](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/1?site=stackoverflow&key=Pw9D)judG8FE4tJR3qjUTA((&filter=!T6o*9_naf.jY-3uDW.) (has 10K quota)

Also, I recommend to [use a filter](https://stackapps.com/questions/4490/how-to-strip-out-certain-fields-from-the-stack-exchange-api-json-response).