# What is the root cause for too many request issue?

Tags: support, api-v2.2, rate-limit, quota

I am getting the following error when importing questions under a particular tag name:

> {"error_id":502,"error_message":"too many requests from this IP, more
>   requests available in 56100
>   seconds","error_name":"throttle_violation"}

What is the root cause for this issue and how to resolve it?
What is the maximum limit?

Answer (score 1):

That error means that **you have used up your API quota for the day.**

You are allowed either 300 or 10,000 API requests per day for each IP address, or app, depending on whether you use an application `key` and/or an `access_token`.

See:

1. [The "Throttles" documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle)
2. [What are the API request limits? (FAQ)](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work)
3. [Request Throttling Limits (FAQ)](https://stackapps.com/questions/1143/request-throttling-limits)

Note that [you must pass the `key` with every call to get the quota benefit](https://stackapps.com/a/6962/7653).