# Can I retrieve question comment count as part of a search query?

Tags: discussion, api, comments

I'm looking for a `comment_count` property in the results of `/search/advanced` to get a count of comments under a question.

Is there an undocumented `q` for `/search/advanced` that gives a `comment_count` property for returned question objects?

Or is making a new request, with gathered question id's, to `/questions/{ids}/comments` and then looping and counting comments per question id the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the `question` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question). `comment_count` has been available since API version 2.2 but it is not returned by default.

You must **create and use [a custom filter](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653)** that includes `comment_count`.

So:
        [`/2.2/search/advanced?q=cheese whiz&site=stackoverflow` (Try it)](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=cheese%20whiz&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

does not return `comment_count`, but:

[`/2.2/search/advanced?q=cheese whiz&site=stackoverflow&filter=!JDuPcYJf3SMj*XSgk.VuM)Yu4HKS_cpasj` (Try it)](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=activity&q=cheese%20whiz&filter=!JDuPcYJf3SMj*XSgk.VuM)Yu4HKS_cpasj&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

does, for example. (Scroll down on both pages to see the query results.)