# Can I pass multiple filters?

Tags: support, api, filter

I've tried adding `filter=total` and `filter=withbody` in the same request but get the following error:

```
{"error_id":400,"error_message":"Invalid filter specified","error_name":"bad_parameter"}
```

How should I format an API request to `/questions` with two filters specified?

I also tried `filter="withbody, total"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot pass multiple filters.  But the good news is you don't need to.

**Just [create a custom filter](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653).**

In your case, you might first [set the edit tool to use `withbody`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search#filter=withbody), and then further edit the filter to check the box next to *.wrapper* -> *total*, in the edit tool.

When you do that, you get a custom filter like `!BHTP)ZqRO*RussQSam5gFh2.5-X*0T` -- which you can see in action with queries like:

[/2.2/search?pagesize=1&intitle=orange& ... &filter=!BHTP)ZqRO*RussQSam5gFh2.5-X*0T](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?pagesize=1&intitle=orange&site=stackoverflow&filter=!BHTP)ZqRO*RussQSam5gFh2.5-X*0T)

Comment: Thanks - that worked for me. How long does the filter stay valid for?

Comment: It should stay valid indefinitely (mine do).  There is an outside chance that some future API version may make some filters obsolete, but you'd get ample warning if that was to happen.