# How to use shallow_user?

Tags: support, api, users

I can not understand how to access the summary information about the user's reputation. How to use the [shallow_user](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/shallow-user) object ?

I tried:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/shallow-user/2765346/reputation?site=stackoverflow
```

and

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2765346/shallow-user?site=stackoverflow
```

Doesn't work.
I want to access the total reputation of the user, not the full history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *use* `shallow_user`; several routes (can) return it.

If you want the reputation for a user, you would typically use the `/users/{ids}` route.  EG:
          [/2.2/users/2765346?site=stackoverflow](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2765346?site=stackoverflow)

If you just want the reputation and not a lot of other stuff [**use a filter**](https://stackapps.com/questions/4490/how-to-strip-out-certain-fields-from-the-stack-exchange-api-json-response). EG:
          [/2.2/users/2765346?site=stackoverflow&filter=!40D.p(1f74CtdIRr7](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2765346?site=stackoverflow&filter=!40D.p(1f74CtdIRr7)