# How do I get information about top users of a Stack Exchange community?

Tags: support, api, users

I was going through the stack exchange API and I want to extract information about, say, top 20 users of a particular stack exchange community. How do I use the API for that?

I tried on  [this page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users) but could not get desired results. I am only getting random information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `/users` route works perfectly fine for showing the top users (of all time).

For example to get the top 20 [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com) users, use:

[/2.2/users?pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=math](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=!23IYX9Jrkz9TSm(1W6hyR&site=math&run=true)

Which gives **the same results as [the top users page on math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all).**

EG:

```
{
  "items": [ {
      "reputation": 431528,
      "user_id": 12042,
      "display_name": "Brian M. Scott"
    }, {
      "reputation": 429508,
      "user_id": 6312,
      "display_name": "Andr&#233; Nicolas"
    },{ 
      "reputation": 260417,
      "user_id": 8508,
      "display_name": "Robert Israel"
    }, {
      "reputation": 259414,
      "user_id": 622,
      "display_name": "Asaf Karagila"
    },
    ... etc.
```

Comment: Can it be extended to also show location of the person (if available) ?

Comment: Yes, just [change the filter](https://stackapps.com/a/4491) that you use.  For example: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=!23IYX9JrmObYre7pzeX1(&site=math&run=true